# How to add a margin on both sides and center the text in a paragraph?

Tags: css, margin, paragraph

http://img.cmsszablony.pl/images/2014/02/12/paragraphs_helps.png - image to help

How to add margin left and right on both sides and middle text in line with text on right side? Please answer my question.

This is my code HTML:

```
<div class="row1 gensmall wrap">        
<p class="alignleft">{TOTAL_USERS_ONLINE}<br />{TOTAL_USERS}{TOTAL_FEMALE}{TOTAL_MALE}{COUNTER}</p> 
<p class="alignright">{POSTED_TODAY}<br />{USERS_OF_THE_DAY_LIST} {USERS_OF_THE_DAY_COUNT}</p>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrap {
display: table;
width:100%;
}
.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Please to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

#### [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/snB7B/)

just add this in your **CSS**

```
p{
    margin:10px;
}
```

Note: Just resize the window if the text breaks.

Comment: If this answer solves the issue just click the check button to close this question. :)

Comment: ok, but i'm still have problem how auto middle text? look img.cmsszablony.pl/images/2014/02/12/seww.png –

Comment: try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/snB7B/1/).You need to add another `p` and set its width.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it would be easier to add padding to the container:

`.row1 { padding: 0 20px }`

As far as aligning the text, I'm not sure what you need.

Comment: ok i'm added margin but how auto middle text? 

look
http://img.cmsszablony.pl/images/2014/02/12/seww.png

Comment: What does "auto middle" mean? I would assume you mean "center" but  you have two separate sections of text, they can't both be centered.